# jQuery selector: How do I select the outer div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class='com_box'>
  <div class='com_box_c'>
    <div class='com_box_info'>
      <a id='quote'>quote</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click in a#quote i want to add a textarea after '.com_box'.

How do I select the outer div? Here is my no working try so far:

```
$('a#quote').click(
  function() {
    var com_box = $(this).parent('div.com_box');
    com_box.after('<textarea>....</textarea>');
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

```
var com_box = $(this).closest("div.com_box");
```

or

```
var com_box = $(this).parents("div.com_box:first");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

Replace

```
var com_box = $(this).parent('div.com_box');
```

with

```
var com_box = $(this).closest('div.com_box');


$('#quote').click(
  function() {
    $(this).closest('div.com_box').after('<textarea>....</textarea>');
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `$(this).parent('div.com_box')` will return any results, as `parent` only will return immediate parents. You probably just want `$('div.com_box')` for that (or `$(this).closest('div.com_box')`).

Answer (score 1):

Use `closest()` as `.com_box` is not a direct parent of the `#quote` element:

```
$('a#quote').click(function() {
    var com_box = $(this).closest('div.com_box');
    com_box.after('<textarea>....</textarea>');
});
```

Using `$(this).parent().parent().parent()` would also work but that's what `closest()` is for. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#quote').bind('click' function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().prepend('<textarea></textarea>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`var com_box = $(this).parent('div.com_box');`

will not work but

`var com_box = $(this).parents('div.com_box');`

will work!

Take note the plural word is used: parents.